# QT-Graphics - How to constrain the item's movement

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt

I am doing a picture mingling project using QGraphics Scene. So I am placing the pictures inside the QGraphicsscene as QgraphicspixmapItem. But the problem is when I am moving the itm(by mouse drag), the QGraphics view is automatically expanding. I want to constrain this action. Can anybody help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I used the QGraphicsScene->signal(cnanged).

I combined this with apppropriate function which checks the selected item's position and maintains it within the given area.

Answer (score 1):

Minimal code sample might help.  Did you specify a [sceneRect](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qgraphicsview.html#sceneRect-prop)?  Note this question:

[QGraphicsView scrolling and image scaling/cropping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489754/qgraphicsview-scrolling-and-image-scaling-cropping)

...and [this thread on QtCentre](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/11873-Problems-understanding-QGraphicsScene):

> Q: Are the boundaries "hard"? In other words: What happens if I 
> create a QGraphicsScene with QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 500, 500) 
> and then try to put an item let's say at position (-50,-50)?
>
> A: No, the framework is quite flexible. In fact if you don't 
> specify a sceneRect it will grow as you add items to encompass
> them all.

Comment: Still the problem persists, even after I added the sceneRect.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'll have to subclass `QGraphicsPixmapItem` to re-implement the [QGraphicsItem::itemChange()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qgraphicsitem.html#itemChange) method.

Have a look at [the help page regarding this function](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qgraphicsitem.html#itemChange) : there is an example which demonstrates exactly what you are trying to do :

```
QVariant Component::itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value)
{
   if (change == ItemPositionChange && scene()) {
      // value is the new position.
      QPointF newPos = value.toPointF();
      QRectF rect = scene()->sceneRect();
      if (!rect.contains(newPos)) {
         // Keep the item inside the scene rect.
         newPos.setX(qMin(rect.right(), qMax(newPos.x(), rect.left())));
         newPos.setY(qMin(rect.bottom(), qMax(newPos.y(), rect.top())));
         return newPos;
      }
  }
  return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to obtain that directly, rather than deriving a class

Comment: @prabhakaran : I never did it (and I guess it isn't very efficient and clean) but maybe you could handle that at the scene level : if the scene changes, it emits a signal. You could then check the current item's position and adapt it if needed with `QGraphicsItem::setPos()`